# Compiler complains about "missing return statement" even though it is impossible to reach condition where return statement would be missing

Tags: java

In the following method, the compiler complains about a *missing return statement* even though there is only a single path through the method, and it contains a `return` statement. Suppressing the error requires another `return` statement.

```
public int foo() {
    if (true) {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Given that the [Java compiler can recognize infinite loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958563/does-java-recognize-infinite-loops), why doesn't it handle this situation as well? The linked question hints, but doesn't provide details for this specific case.

Comment: in `foo4()` the compiler is not so clever that it understands that the function always returns 5. It just checks that not all code paths return something.

Comment: if statement is treated specially in flow analysis, see JLS 14.21: *The if statement, ... is handled in an unusual manner. For this reason, it is discussed separately at the end of this section*

Comment: @irreputable In the future, if you want to dispute a question closure, consider flagging the post for moderator review or posting on [meta]. It's a lot more constructive than running around insulting people or vandalizing posts.

Comment: Interesting question. If one adds a return statement after the `if`, one then gets a "dead code" warning from the compiler (at least it does when I try it in Eclipse). So the compiler definitely knows that the return statement inside the `if` will always execute.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[JLS 14.21, Unreachable Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) is the section that deals with this:

> The if statement, whether or not it has an else part, is handled in an unusual manner. For this reason, it is discussed separately at the end of this section.

Ultimately it has to do with how conditional compilation is handled. Consider this method:

```
public int foo() {
    if (DEBUG) {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

If `DEBUG` is `static final boolean true;` you might think the compiler should be smart enough to realize the method will always return `5`. But if it's changed to `false`, the code is no longer valid.

The method must be valid for all paths through the method *without a source code change*, allowing optimizing compilers to omit bytecode without source modifications regardless of the flag's value.

The [very end of the linked JLS section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) goes in to significant detail.

Comment: @DaveNewton : Please update second url( very end of the linked JLS section)

Comment: @Nandkumar Update it to what?

Comment: @DaveNewton : Actually it was java.sun.com, now it is oracle, links has been changed. I modified 2nd url by mistake, now I was trying to correct it but I can't find your content on oracle docs for java lang specs.

Comment: I would rephrase the explanation a little bit. The rule isn't for the benefit of optimizing compilers -- these could omit the unreachable code under either rule -- it's for the benefit of the programmer, who doesn't want to be forced to go hunting for and deleting `if (DEBUG)`s every time they change the value, because that would be a pain. Also it allows the old `if (true) return;` as a way of debugging parts of a function, or a place to put a breakpoint.

Comment: @Owen It's for the benefit of *both*, as explained in the details JLS section linked to.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why the compiler is complaining has to do with this key point from [Section 14.21 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21), discussing unreachable statements:

> Except for the special treatment of `while`, `do`, and `for` statements whose condition expression has the constant value `true`, the values of expressions are not taken into account in the flow analysis.

Note that `if` is *not* one of the statements that has special handling of `true` constant conditions. The reason it is excluded from this special handling is to allow `if` to be used as a form of conditional compilation, as Dave Newton explained in his answer.

Comment: Good point yet I accepted @Dave Newton's answer as he also already mentioned good things. Thank you very much.