# Why is an error issued with an if statement in Java even though it is always true?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compiler complains about “missing return statement” even though it is impossible to reach condition where return statement would be missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863676/compiler-complains-about-missing-return-statement-even-though-it-is-impossible)

The following method in Java compiles fine.

```
public String temp() {
    while(true) {
        if(true) {
            // Do something.
        }
    }
}
```

The method has an explicit return type which is `java.lang.String` with no `return` statement though it compiles fine. The following method however fails to compile.

```
public String tempNew() {
    if(true) {
        return "someString";
    }        
}
```

A compile-time error is issued indicating "*missing `return` statement*" even though the condition specified with the `if` statement is always true (it has a `boolean` constant that is never going to be changed neither by reflection). The method must be modified something like the following for its successful compilation.

```
public String tempNew() {
    if(true) {
        return "someString";
    } else {
        return "someString";
    }
}
```

or

```
public String tempNew() {
    if(true) {
        return "someString";
    }

    return "someString";
}
```

Regarding the first case with the `while` loop, the second case appears to be legal though it fails to compile.

Is there a reason in the second case beyond one of the compiler's features.

Comment: It's funny because (in the `if (true)` method) if you don't have an `else` clause it won't compile due to the missing `return` statement; but if you do, the compiler complains of dead code.

Comment: @A. R. S. - Is dead code warning issued by some IDE? I can't see with NetBeans.

Comment: @Tiny I received the warning in Eclipse, not sure for NetBeans though.

Comment: @A. R. S. - Thanks for the reply. I will try with Eclipse later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is dead code. The dead code analysis is done in a separate pass to the method return analysis, which does some more in-depth analysis that looks inside branch conditions.

Comment: Nice answer. It really recommend you to give some more explanation so that it will be helpful to others in future.

Comment: Is *dead code warning* issued by some IDE? I can't see with NetBeans.

Answer (score 1):

From the java tutorial:
You can implement an infinite loop using the while statement as follows:

```
while (true){
    // your code goes here
}
```

so the compiler knows this is infinite, and therefore may not return - ie not necessarily needing a return statement.

The `if (true)` line (on it's own), on the other hand will return and therefore needs to cover all returning branches.