# How do I return boolean in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

```
public boolean isOdd (int value) {
    if ((value % 2)== 0){ 
        return false; 
    } else if ((value % 2) > 0){ 
        return true; 
    }
}
```

I get an error saying:
private boolean isOdd(int value) throws Exception{
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
This method must return a result of type boolean

I tried doing:

```
public boolean isOdd (int value) {
    boolean isOdd =  ((value % 2) > 0);
    return true; 
} 

public boolean isEven (int value) {
    boolean isEven = ((value % 2) > 0);
    return true;
}
```

and it only returns true as an output.

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong here!

Comment: This is because you have no `else` clause.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiler complains about "missing return statement" even though it is impossible to reach condition where return statement would be missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863676/compiler-complains-about-missing-return-statement-even-though-it-is-impossible)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your first code snippet is causing an error because you have not catered for the `else` case. You do not need an `else if` here as you want the second condition to execute in all cases where the if statement is not satisfied. Try changing it to:

```
public boolean isOdd (int value) {

    if ((value % 2)== 0){ 
        return false; 
    } 
    else { return true; }

}
```

or more simply:

```
public boolean isOdd (int value) {
    return ((value % 2) != 0);
}
```

Comment: More generally, the error message should be treated first as an indication that there is a problem in the logic of the method. There is a way of reaching the end of the method the programmer did not expect. Finding and fixing that problem, as in this answer, will often lead to simpler, cleaner code than reflexively adding an else clause or return statement.

Comment: Hmm I get that the second one is way simpler than the first one but what is ! supposed to be? And how can ((value % 2) != 0) determine whether to return true or false?

Comment: `!` should be read as "not".  So `(value % 2) != 0` should be read as "value mod 2 is not equal to zero," and that statement is either true or false, so it is a `boolean` by itself.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a default return value in the first snippet, aka one that is not inside any if.

Comment: I don't know how to do that but I solved the problem anyway thanks for answering!

Comment: Look at Stochastically's answer for an example on how to set a default value. This is really important for you to understand because all Java methods (except `void` ones) must return a default value.

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
public boolean isOdd(int value) {
    return (value % 2) != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need an else or at least another return. If neither of your if statements match then nothing will be returned and that is not allowed.

```
public boolean isOdd (int value) {

if ((value % 2)== 0){ 
return false; } 

else if ((value % 2) > 0){ 
return true; }

return true;

}
```

You could replace the method with the below method:

```
public boolean isOdd (int value) {
return (value % 2) != 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The compile error would go away if you added an `else` statement, i.e.

```
if ((value % 2)== 0) { 
    return false;
} else if ((value % 2) > 0){ 
   return true;
} else {
   return ??; // default value
}
```

Comment: `-true` or `FileNotFound`?

Answer (score 1):

What if `((value % 2) < 0)`? You aren't catering for that possibility, and there is no return path if that happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isEven (int value) {
  return value%2==0;
} 

public boolean isOdd (int value) {
  return value%2!=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
public boolean isOdd (int value) {
    if ((value % 2) == 0)
        return false; 
    return true; 
}
```