# Why this for statement shows Dead code in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

In this class, I defined a constructor that initializes an array and fill it with Point2D.Double. I want to define a toString method that outputs the Point2D.Double in the array. So inside the toString method, I make a for loop that returns every Point2D.Double in the array. The problem is, I don't know why Eclipse tells me that the update in the for statement is dead code.

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;


public class SimplePolygon {

    public int n; // number of vertices of the polygon
    public Point2D.Double[] vertices; // vertices[0..n-1] around the polygon
                                // boundary

public SimplePolygon(int size) {
    n = size;
    vertices = new Point2D.Double[n]; // creates array with n size. Elements are doubles.
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Point2D.Double point = new Point2D.Double(Math.random() * 6, Math.random() * 6);
        vertices[i] = point;
    }

}

public String toString() {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        return "" + vertices[i];
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: [See](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8863676/1391249).

Comment: Change your toString(): 1) Create a new variable `String s = "";` 2) Change 'return "" + vertices[i]' to `s += vertices[i];`, 3) after the loop completes, `return s;`

Answer (score 5):

I too was puzzled by this.  (And the other answers!)  So I cut-and-pasted it into Eclipse to see what it *actually* says.

And what Eclipse is *actually* says is that `i++` is unreachable in this line.

```
   for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
```

And in fact, that is correct!  If you ever enter the loop body, the body will unconditionally return.  Hence the `i++` can never be executed.

Note also that this is a warning not an error.  This code is not invalid according to the JLS rules about unreachability.

---

You are right to be puzzled by the other explanations.  The final `return` statement is reachable.  Consider the case where the class is instantiated with a negative value for `n` (or `size`).  In that case, the `for` loop body will never be executed, and control will go to the final `return`.

However, their suggestions as to how to fix the problem are correct.  You should not have a `return` in the loop body.

Answer (score 4):

<s>The problem is because of the `return` statement in the `for` loop. Remember, whenever you use `return`, you immediately end the method and stop running any code. That means that your `toString` method will loop exactly only once, returning only `vertices[0]`. The second return below the loop never has a chance to execute, so is considered dead code.</s>

This is actually incorrect! See [Stephan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25829745/646543) for a better/accurate explanation of what's going on.

Regardless, you still need to fix your code. Instead of returning something inside the loop, you probably want to *combine* the values and return them all at once at the very end. An easy way to do this might be:

```
public String toString() {
    String output = "";

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        output += vertices[i] + " ";
    }

    return output;
}
```

Now, instead of returning immediately, we're *accumulating* values in the loop and returning at the very end.

(Note that the code here isn't very efficient -- you'd probably want to use something like String.join or StringBuilder instead, but if you're a beginner, this works for now)