# Why do I not need to provide a return value after an endless loop?

Tags: java

**Answer**: The top answer of this thread basically answers my question: [Missing return statement in a non-void method compiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789832/missing-return-statement-in-a-non-void-method-compiles?lq=1).

---

I wonder why I do not need to return a value in this `private` method?

```
public class Test {
  private String testLoop() {
    while(true) { }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.testLoop();
  }
}
```

I feel like this should not compile. However, it compiles fine. Where is this defined to be legal?

In this context, I find it weird that changing the method to:

```
private String testLoop() {
  while(true) { 
    if(false == true) { 
      break;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

requires me to provide a return type even though *javap* tells me that the compiler produces the exact same byte code for both implementations of `testLoop`.

So how and when does the Java compiler decide if a method actually needs a return value?

---

Unfortunately, an answer was deleted which mentioned the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). I guess the Java compiler does not put effort on tracing methods like the example given above since it cannot find all possible loops in a general setting.

Comment: What do you deem to be illegal about it?

Comment: Interestingly as soon as you put a `break;` inside the loop java gets upset again. The java compiler is more clever than I had imagined

Comment: The `if(false == true)` is explicitly excluded from the flow control check by the language specification to allow constructs like `if(DEBUG) …` where `DEBUG` is a `static final boolean`, i.e. a compile-time constant. So this `if(…) break;` statement is treated as “could happen or not” even if the condition expression is a compile-time constant. So you can change the value of the `DEBUG` constant without breaking the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private String testLoop() {
    while(true) { }  //infinite loop
}
```

Above method never return since there is infinite loop there. So it is not expecting return Or it will never reach return.

Comment: +1 Add a break; inside the loop and the compiler will swear!

Answer (score 1):

your while loop `while(true) { }` will never end so compiler is not expecting for a return statement.If the compiler finds the loop will end then it wil expect for a return statement.You can manually test it.try with `int i=1;while(i<0)` this will give compile error and compiler will ask you to retrun a statement

Comment: Not the best example, because the loop body is unreachable..

Comment: @FranzEbner sorry i didnt get you

Comment: @FranzEbner's point is that the body of while(1<0) will _never_ be executed,  so it may not be the best example either.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor ohh now I got,it was just an example.well i will modify it soon

Comment: @FranzEbner Thanks for your comment,now I updated please see it

Comment: @javaBeginner Better!

Answer (score 1):

The method

```
private String testLoop() {
    while(true) { }
}
```

doesn't really have a return point during the compilation, which means that when it's compiled there never comes a time in which it "looks for" a return..

This isn't a good practice of course and empty cycles especially those with `true` condition should pop up as an error in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

while(true) { } does not let to execute any further statement you write

```
private String testLoop() {
        while(true) { }
         //any code at this point is not reachable since it wont come out of while loop. So return statement just like any java code wont be reachable.
      }
```

Answer (score -4):

your calling the testloop method, and not requiring a return value....if you wrote it like this, then the private method would have to return something.

```
String result = test.testloop();
```

Comment: Edited to show correct language, thanks @david99world