# why java does not report missing return error when return is only available in if-block?

Tags: java, syntax

This is a dup question, already answered in [Why do I not need to provide a return value after an endless loop? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952598/why-do-i-not-need-to-provide-a-return-value-after-an-endless-loop)

I wonder why the following codes are OK. (From Leetcode #1 two sum).

I think java must report missing return statement error, but it's not in this case ?

Although code description makes sure there will be a valid answer, but why writing the code in the following way make sure compiler won't report the missing return statement error ?

```
public int[] twoSum1(int[] nums, int target) {
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) 
        for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) 
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) 
                return new int[]{i, j};

    // Why we can miss the following return statement here ?
    // return new int[0];
}
```

```
public int[] twoSum2(int[] nums, int target) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> idx = new HashMap<>(); 
    for (int j = 0; ; j++) { 
        int x = nums[j];
        
        if (idx.containsKey(target - x)) 
            return new int[]{idx.get(target - x), j}; 
        idx.put(x, j); 
    }

    // Why we can miss the following return statement here ?
    // return new int[0];}
```

Also if I setup a case without correct ans, the JVM will report the error during execution:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2147483647 out of bounds for length 2
        at Solution.twoSum1(Solution.java:5)
        at Solution.main(Solution.java:19)
```

Comment: Your i-loop never terminates, so code after the i-loop is unreachable. The index out of bounds is because (1) you have no limit on your i-loop, and (2) 2147483647 + 1 is negative.