# Interesting code snippet

Tags: c#, function, methods, compiler-errors, return

I've always thought that a method different than void must return a value no matter what however if we have this for example

```
    private int Foo()
    {
        while (true)
        {

        }
    }
```

There's no compile-time errors here and I think that's because the loop is infinite C# can guarantee that it wont terminate without returning a value. Am I correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a non-void function with `reachable` end point has to return a value.

For more info, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16795317/2300466) by Eric Lippert.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the function is going to run forever the return value is redundant so the compiler just ignore it.