# Every Java non-void method must return value

Tags: java

[Java tutorial says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) :

Any method that is not declared void must contain a return statement with a corresponding return value, like this:

```
return returnValue;
```

However, it is quite true. It is possible to create a non-void return method without return statement.

```
public class MyClass {

    public String myMethod()  {
        while (true) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

Question : It is clear that compiler infers that there is no way to get out of the infinite loop (and return value), however should not language rules be enforced regardless?

Comment: I'm gonna have to go put that in an IDE, I'm pretty sure it's a compiler error...

Comment: What does the JLS say? That's the specification. The Java tutorial is not. it's just a tutorial, which takes some shortcuts.

Comment: Interesting, no compilation error.

Comment: @JBNizet https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5

Comment: are you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958563/does-java-recognize-infinite-loops

Comment: Your question seems unclear. Please consider rephrasing the thesis of your question. If you're really just asking "should language rules be enforced", the answer is no. It doesn't matter if it doesn't affect the way the program runs.

Comment: Ah I love learning new things. Thanks OP, follow YCF's link for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7) says that a return statement is required if the method could complete normally.

> If a method is declared to have a return type, then a compile-time error occurs if the body of the method can complete normally (§14.1).

A later section of the JLS defines certain statements as [unreachable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) if the compiler can prove by specific simple rules (e.g. a while loop with no exit and a constant condition expression evaluating to true makes the rest of the method body unreachable).

Only under this sort of condition is it permissible to omit a return statement.